# Change element value on external website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have such a problem - I want to change value of an element on some external website.

Namely: I have webcam http interface which is password protected and there is a page with motion detection checkbox and "Apply" button (form submit). I want to create simple program with some sort of delayed toggling of motion detection (so I can launch this program and have some time to leave the building before motion detection starts). So I want to change checkbox state and write this change to system. I tried something like this, but that doesn't work:

```
 jQuery.get("http://admin:password@192.168.0.1:12345/motion-page.asp",
       function(data){
         $('input[name="checkbox1"]').prop('checked', false);
         // and there "simulate" clicking on Apply button - submit the form -- don't know how ...
       }
 );
```

Can anybody help me with this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would backtrack from the page that shows when you submit the camera form. See if the form itself is submitting the "turn camera on" variable as GET or POST. If you already know this, then all you would have to do is access the same URL as the form from the camera (assuming it's HTTP accessible on a network like this) and submit that same set of variables.

If you don't want to open a browser to do this, you could write yourself a custom application that submits it for you, but either way you have to open something to make the submission, as a script has to wait [X] amount of time before making the request. The fastest way will be through a browser.

I am not sure you need jquery for this (I never use jquery hardly at all). What I would do on the scripting side, since merely accessing this script means you want to activate the timer most likely, would be to create a timer object in javascript, and then make a single function that either accesses the URL of the camera form submission with the GET string parameters (that's easiest if it's doable via GET, because you wont have to build a form), or, if it's POST, have the function build a form and submit the form via POST to the same URL.

Google how to create a timer in javascript, and google how to automatically submit a form. Doing the code for you would be a waste of my time if you can figure it out on your own. If not, come back and we'll see what we can do :) 
Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I think I know how to post/get classic form on some webpage, but the submitting there is done by some (private?) function validate() and I dont know either what is going on in it or how to call it remotely from inside of my script :(

Comment: Right, so run it through a debug proxy like Charles, and inspect the request, if you can. Otherwise I am out of ideas :( Sorry.

Comment: Hey man! That's perfect! Charles works like a charm :) Everything solved now, I know URL to enable/disable motion detection. Thanks very much !!! :)

Comment: Hah! Glad I could help :) - for the record, I said charles because I was not paying attention- I have been using Fiddler lately because it's much more free than Charles. Just food for thought. Same dif, really, if you only use it for basic request debugging.

Comment: Ok, I will try Fiddler too, anyway - Charles is only trial... thx again :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not after hitting the submit button, or after checking the box, have javascript actually run a timer? Look into the timer functions in js or jquery if that's more your thing. Not sure if you need it written to disk or whatever... since you're not giving much info, but whatever data you're wanting recorded could be captured when the box is checked and can be submitted along with the form whenever the timer runs out.
Submitting a form in jquery is simple:
http://api.jquery.com/submit/
:)

Comment: thanks, but actually I don't know how to hit the button programmatically, only manually through the web UI or is it what you meant? I also wanted to make it more instant this way rather than manually starting the browser, enter password, find the check button and then submitting ...

Comment: Then your question was very confusing. I understood that you want to be using the computer that is running the application, check a box, leave the building, and have the script run a timer to submit data some time later. Either way you have to provide SOME kind of input to 'submit' your form-- IE you have to do it from somewhere. Be more clear on how you want this to work because you've totally confused me now.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, maybe I am confusing you because of my bad english, sorry :) well, it is like this: IP camera connected to local router, computer connected to local router. UI of camera is closed (I dont have source files or anything - just web interface). Simply I want to find out the way, how to enable checkbutton in camera UI from this computer with for example javascript / jQuery / ... I only know that I can login into camera UI with get/post method passing it username and password and then there is some asp page with this checkbox I want to enable ... I hope thats better :)

Comment: Ahhhhhhhh Okay. I'm going to write you a new answer then because I don't think that what I have in mind will fit in a comment.